# Cost of OpenCL get_local_id()

Tags: cuda, opencl, nvidia

I have a simple scan kernel, which calculates scans of several blocks in a loop. I noticed that performance somewhat rises when get_local_id() is stored inside a local variable instead of calling it inside the loop. So to summarize with code, this:

```
__kernel void LocalScan_v0(__global const int *p_array, int n_array_size, __global int *p_scan)
{
    const int n_group_offset = get_group_id(0) * SCAN_BLOCK_SIZE;
    p_array += n_group_offset;
    p_scan += n_group_offset;
    // calculate group offset

    const int li = get_local_id(0); // *** local id cached ***
    const int gn = get_num_groups(0);
    __local int p_workspace[SCAN_BLOCK_SIZE];
    for(int i = n_group_offset; i < n_array_size; i += SCAN_BLOCK_SIZE * gn) {
        LocalScan_SingleBlock(p_array, p_scan, p_workspace, li);

        p_array += SCAN_BLOCK_SIZE * gn;
        p_scan += SCAN_BLOCK_SIZE * gn;
    }
    // process all the blocks in the array (each block size SCAN_BLOCK_SIZE)
}
```

Has throughput of 74 GB/s on GTX-780, while this:

```
__kernel void LocalScan_v0(__global const int *p_array, int n_array_size, __global int *p_scan)
{
    const int n_group_offset = get_group_id(0) * SCAN_BLOCK_SIZE;
    p_array += n_group_offset;
    p_scan += n_group_offset;
    // calculate group offset

    const int gn = get_num_groups(0);
    __local int p_workspace[SCAN_BLOCK_SIZE];
    for(int i = n_group_offset; i < n_array_size; i += SCAN_BLOCK_SIZE * gn) {
        LocalScan_SingleBlock(p_array, p_scan, p_workspace, get_local_id(0));
        // *** local id polled inside the loop ***

        p_array += SCAN_BLOCK_SIZE * gn;
        p_scan += SCAN_BLOCK_SIZE * gn;
    }
    // process all the blocks in the array (each block size SCAN_BLOCK_SIZE)
}
```

Has only 70 GB/s on the same hardware. The only difference is whether the call to get_local_id() is inside or outside of the loop. The code in LocalScan_SingleBlock() is pretty much described in [this GPU Gems article](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html).

Now this brings some questions. I always imagined that thread id is stored inside some register, and access to it is as fast as to any thread-local variable. This doesn't seem to be the case. I always used to have habit of caching the local id in a variable with reluctance of an old "C" programmer who wouldn't call a function in a loop, had he expect it to return the same value every time, but I didn't seriously think it would make any difference.

Any ideas as to why this might be? I didn't do any checking on the compiled binary code. Does anyone have the same experience? Is it the same with `threadIdx.x` in CUDA? How about ATI platforms? Is this behavior described somewhere? I quickly scanned through CUDA Best Practices, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Please, do not remove the CUDA tag. Although the code itself is not in CUDA, the issue is manifesting on NVIDIA hardware, and is closely related to how CUDA's threadIdx is implemented and how it affects runitme of programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a guess, but as per the Khronos page

http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/get_local_id.html

get_local_id() isn't defined to return a constant value (merely size_t). That may mean that, as far as the compiler is aware, it may not be allowed to perform certain optimisations compared with a constant local_id because the return of the function value may change in the eyes of the compiler (even though it wont per-thread)

Comment: That would be really silly from NVIDA to leave it like that, especially since in CUDA threadIdx is a variable and not a function. It would be easily solved by declaring get_local_id() as a macro. Also, one would expect to read about it somewhere. A good guess, nevertheless.

Comment: Well, its not up to nvidia what the opencl spec says, and if the issue is compiler optimisations with it being a non-const function which can't be optimised away then its likely independent of how the threadidx is represented in the hardware. Additionally, wouldn't a macro be constant rather than non constant? As per the actual reference to the spec in the link, its specifically under the section "Built in functions" and under "Work-item related functions" which means it might additionally _technically_ be incorrect to implement it as a macro. Just more guessing

Comment: NVIDIA is the one who is writing the compiler. You will learn that when it comes to vendor's implementations, the specification is not the law :). What i meant is that the OpenCL compiler would just #define get_local_id(coord) (threadIdx.x * (~(coord | coord >> 1) & 1) + threadIdx.y * ...) which looks like a function and evaluates to a compile-time constant. Not that they needed to do that, but perhaps it is simpler to imageine.

Comment: You might be actually right, after getting into PTX assembly and all that, I noticed that the compiler won't reuse expressions such as e.g. "get_local_id() * 2 + 1". So it seems to be expecting it to change in the middle of execution. Well, that's real dumb if you ask me. On the other hand, using get_local_id() instead is usually a way to reduce register usage. It is the same with get_local_size(), even if using the reqd_work_group_size attribute.